# Searching through XML in T-SQL with conditions

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, ssms

I am trying to get the correct info from an XML data type into regular scalar variables based on conditions, however I am having trouble getting the correct info back.

Here is the XML I am searching through:

```
<Loop2420>
                <NM1>
                  <F98_1>PW</F98_1>
                  <F1065>2</F1065>
                </NM1>
                <N3>
                  <F166>81715 DOCTOR CARRE</F166>
                </N3>
                <N4>
                  <F19>INDIO</F19>
                  <F156>CA</F156>
                  <F116>92201</F116>
                </N4>
              </Loop2420>
              <Loop2420>
                <NM1>
                  <F98_1>45</F98_1>
                  <F1065>2</F1065>
                </NM1>
                <N3>
                  <F166>51250 MECCA AVE</F166>
                </N3>
                <N4>
                  <F19>COACHELLA</F19>
                  <F156>CA</F156>
                  <F116>92236</F116>
                </N4>
              </Loop2420>
```

Basically I need to get the numbers from <'F116'> but only if <'F98_1'> is equal to 'PW'.

I have tried:

```
declare @zip varchar(30)
select @zip = T.value('(F116)[1]','varchar(30)')
        from @TransactionXML.nodes('/Loop2420/N4') Trans(T)
        where T.value('(/Loop2420/NM1/F98_1)[1]','varchar(30)') = 'PW'
```

But that sometimes returns the value from <'F116'> even if <'F98_1'> is equal to '45'.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the test in the XQuery itself and clamp it to the node you're checking:

```sql
SELECT @zip = T.value('(N4/F116)[1]', 'varchar(30)')
FROM @TransactionXML.nodes('/Loop2420') Trans(T)
WHERE T.exist('NM1/F98_1[text()="PW"]') = 1
```

If `PW` is not a static value, use the `sql:variable()` or `sql:column()` function to incorporate it in the query.

Comment: @H22 Then you'll need to amend the question to show what you want the actual result to be and/or input on which this fails. [This query gives `92201`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f49476a38d6a10065e534dec1aa3f463), which I'd expect to be correct based on your input. Do note that if there is more than one matching node, the result will be non-deterministic no matter what -- you'd need to put in some kind of order if that's not desired.

Comment: @H22 Then your actual query probably looks different from mine, too. Take care that you do not inadvertently test for existence on the wrong node, though (we want to check for existence of the `NM1/F98_1` node on the same level as the value we fetch from `N4/F116`).